# Double integral whose answer doesn't make any sense

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

**SOLVED: READ BOTTOM**

How do I calculate the following double integral? I attempted multiple times and got the same answer (both by integrating with respect to y first and by integrating with respect to x, using IBP). I keep getting $\ln({\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}}$); the answer is given as $\ln({\frac{7\sqrt{6}}{12})}$.

What am I doing wrong? The original question is

$$ \iint_R \frac{x}{(2+xy)^2}dA, R={(x,y): 0 \le x \le 5, 1 \le y \le 2}$$

My steps:

$$ \int_{x = 0}^5 \int_{y = 1}^2 \frac{x}{(2+xy)^2} dydx $$

Solving first integral:

$$ x \int_{y = 1}^2 (2+xy)^{-2} dy$$

$$ u = (2+xy) $$
$$ \frac{du}{dy} = x $$
$$ dy = \frac{du}{x} $$

$$ \int_{y = 1}^2 u^{-2} du$$

$$ = -[u^{-1}] \Big|_{y=1}^2 $$

$$ = -[(2+xy)^{-1}] \Big|_{y=1}^2 $$

$$ = - (2+2x)^{-1} + (2+x)^{-1} $$

Now evaluate the x-integral:

$$ \int_{x=0}^5 [(2+x)^{-1} - (2+2x)^{-1}] dx $$

$$ = \int_{x=0}^5 (2+x)^{-1} dx - \int_{x=0}^5 (2+2x)^{-1} dx $$

$$ = \ln{|2+x|} \Big|_{x=0}^4 - \frac{\ln{|2+2x|}}{2} \Big|_{x=0}^4 $$

$$ = [\ln{6} - \ln{2}] - [\frac{\ln{10}}{2} - \frac{\ln{2}}{2}] $$

$$ = \ln{3} - \frac{\ln{\sqrt{10}}}{\ln{\sqrt{2}}} $$

$$ = \ln{\frac{3}{\frac{\sqrt{10}}{\sqrt{2}}}} $$

$$ = \ln{\frac{3{\sqrt{2}}}{\sqrt{10}}} $$

$$ = \ln{\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}} $$

And this is how I arrived at $ \ln({\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}})} $! Let me know if I made any mistakes.

Thank you! :)

Just realized I somehow swapped the bounds from $\int_{x=0}^5$ to $\int_{x=0}^4$ halfway through solving. Oops

Comment: Show us the attempt in full, we may see if there's a mistake.

Comment: You need to put your steps in the post. If you don't, it is not possible to say what errors you made.

Comment: Okay, I will edit it and put my steps! This might take a while; I am new to LaTeX notation. Sorry in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use integration by parts to do this, simple substitutions are more than enough.

Let $u=2+xy$ then $du=x dy$ so
$$
\int{x\over(2+xy)^2}dy=\int {1\over u^2}du=-{1\over u}+C
$$
so the definite $y$ integral gives
$$
\int_1^2{x\over(2+xy)^2}dy={-1\over 2+xy}\Biggr|_1^2=-{1\over 2+2x}+{1\over 2+x}
$$
Integrating this over $x$ gives
$$
-\frac12 \log(2+2x)+\log(1+2x)+C
$$
and inserting the limits $x=0$ and $x=2$ gives
$$
-\frac12 \log 12+\log 7 -\frac12\log 2=\log{7\over \sqrt{12\times 2}}=\log{7\sqrt6\over12}.
$$
When I attempted this, I made the error of forgetting to add a 2 to $x$ at the last stage and got a $\sqrt5$. Perhaps you did the same thing?

Comment: Thank you for your solution. While writing out my steps on here, I realized that I somehow switched the bounds from $\int_{x=0}^5$ to $\int_{x=0}^4$ midway through solving... not really sure what I was doing. I am thoroughly embarrassed. Thank you again!

Comment: I worked through a whole textbook of integrals recently and I think I made similar mistakes with about half of them.